# Setting Parameters before api Controller initializes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-apicontroller

I'm trying to pass a parameter for database connection purposes in my apiController constructor.
for example by default in my baseAPIController i neeed the code to be '1'. But in this specific controller I need to change that parameter to '7'. 
The problem is that my BaseAPIController instanciates with '1' and after instantiated even if I send '7' in the property it doesn't change.
How can I set "7" in this specific controller before the baseAPI is initialized?

```
public class ListagemProjetoEletricoWebController :BaseAPIController<ListagemProjetoEletricoBusiness>
{       
    public List<ListagemProjeto> Get(String cpf)
    {
        business.idEmpresa = 7;
        List<ListagemProjeto> listProjetoEletricoWeb = business.GetProjetoEletricoLista(cpf);
        return listProjetoEletricoWeb;
    }
}
```

and in my baseAPIcontroller I have.

```
protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
{
    this.business = new TBusiness();
    this.business.idEmpresa = 1;

    this.business.db = new BaseBusiness(this.business.idEmpresa).db; 

    base.Initialize(controllerContext);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an virtual property in your base class to represent the `idEmpresa`

```
public class BaseAPIController
{
     //Set the default to whatever it is used normally
     public virtual int idEmpresa { get {return 1;} }
}
```

then in your derrived class you override that property

```
public class ListagemProjetoEletricoWebController :BaseAPIController<ListagemProjetoEletricoBusiness>
{
    public override int idEmpresa { get { return 7;} } 
}
```

Then when you set your business idEmpresa use the property instead

```
this.business.idEmpresa = this.idEmpresa;
```

Comment: Hi Johnny, I did as instructions and I get the error "The modifier 'virtual' is not valid for this item".

Comment: sorry the derrived class should use the keyword override

Comment: @ana I've updated my answer,  If that works for you please upvote and mark as correct ;p

Comment: Also, I've changed the => to just '=' because of sintax errors;

Comment: @Ana that syntax is for properties I guess your not on C# 7 Hold on Ill make another update

Comment: @Ana when you switched to use = that changed the properties to a field.  The => is short hand for Property Getter syntax in c# 7.0

Comment: I've market as useful, but I don't have enought reputation for now. As soon I get more points I will be back. promisse

Comment: @Ana there should be there is a checkmark next to the answer you can click, which marks it as answered.  there also is an up arrow to upvote the question